# Custom Form Resizing by Border

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, resize

I have a custom Form with no borders and title bar. I`am using panel(width = 1px) to emulate borders. All work great, except left and top border. When I try to reduce the size of the form(by draging it to right side),it work fine BUT when the size of form  == this.MinimumSize. It start moving to right side. I want only change size, withoust moving...
Here my leftBorder code. How i can modify it to change only size?

```
    private void borderW_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Active = true;

    }


    private void borderW_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Active)
        {
            if (e.X < 0)
            {
                this.Location = new Point(this.Left + e.X, this.Top);
                this.Size = new Size(this.Width - e.X, this.Height);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Size = new Size(this.Width - e.X, this.Height);
                this.Location = new Point(this.Left + e.X, this.Top);
            }
        }
    }

    private void borderW_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Active = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste this function in your form. It is an override that prevents the moving of the form.

However, you must fit it with a condition that makes it only active whenever the left of your form is the same as form.left + form.width(from what i understand from your question.

```
protected override void WndProc( ref Message m )
{
const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 161;
const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
const int HTCAPTION = 2;
const int SC_MOVE = 61456;
if ( (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) && (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MOVE) )
return;
if ( (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) && (m.WParam.ToInt32() == HTCAPTION)
)
return;
base.WndProc( ref m );
}
```

Comment: No, how can FormStartPostion influence on form location, when I'll change location(  this.Location = new Point(this.Left + e.X, this.Top);)

Comment: You are right. Startposition only has influence when the form loads. This answer: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/279387-how-do-i-prevent-form-moving points to a solution. if your form.left is equeal to form.left + form.width, you can kick in this winproc to prevent the moving of the windows.

Comment: And how can i use this? Where i must paste it?

Comment: This doesnt work. Maybe i dont understand what you mean in - @"it only active whenever the left of your form is the same as form.left + form.width". I must do this checking?